# Error Running Apache Beam with python via Dataflow runner

Tags: apache-beam

**Description**

I am currently implementing a batch job with dataflow using apache beam, this works fine when i use direct runner. Changing this throws the below exception, not sure where the error is comming from.

**Code Snippet**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cZse.png)

**Error:**

raceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/beam_mysql/connector/client.py", line 179, in **enter**
self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(**self._config)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 286, in connect
return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 101, in **init**
self.connect(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1095, in connect
self._open_connection()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 268, in _open_connection
raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:41849' (111)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 284, in _execute
response = task()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 357, in 
lambda: self.create_worker().do_instruction(request), request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 597, in do_instruction
return getattr(self, request_type)(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 635, in process_bundle
bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 1003, in process_bundle
input_op_by_transform_id[element.transform_id].process_encoded(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 227, in process_encoded
self.output(decoded_value)
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 526, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 528, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 237, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonElementConsumerSet.receive
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 240, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonElementConsumerSet.receive
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 907, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 908, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1419, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1491, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1417, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 623, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1581, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputHandler.handle_process_outputs
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1694, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputHandler._write_value_to_tag
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 240, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonElementConsumerSet.receive
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 907, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 908, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1419, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1491, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1417, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 623, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1581, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputHandler.handle_process_outputs
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1694, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputHandler._write_value_to_tag
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 240, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonElementConsumerSet.receive
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 907, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 908, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1419, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1507, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1417, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 623, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1571, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputHandler.handle_process_outputs
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 1454, in process
for part, size in self.restriction_provider.split_and_size(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/core.py", line 331, in split_and_size
for part in self.split(element, restriction):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/io/iobase.py", line 1641, in split
estimated_size = restriction.source().estimate_size()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/beam_mysql/connector/source.py", line 49, in estimate_size
return self._splitter.estimate_size()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/beam_mysql/connector/splitters.py", line 48, in estimate_size
return self.source.client.rough_counts_estimator(self.source.query)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/beam_mysql/connector/client.py", line 104, in rough_counts_estimator
with _MySQLConnection(self._config) as conn:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/beam_mysql/connector/client.py", line 182, in **enter**
raise MySQLClientError(f"Failed to connect mysql, Raise exception: {e}")
beam_mysql.connector.errors.MySQLClientError: Failed to connect mysql, Raise exception: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:36247' (111) [while running 'ref_AppliedPTransform_Read-From-Mysql-Read-SDFBoundedSourceReader-ParDo-SDFBoundedSourceDoFn-_7/SplitWithSizing-ptransform-38']

Comment: Can you share a code part please ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun added a snippet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have a connection problem to `MySql` :

Your `traceback` indicates :

```
 mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:41849'
```

[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html#:~:text=The%20error%20(2003)%20Can',one%20configured%20on%20the%20server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html#:%7E:text=The%20error%20(2003)%20Can%27,one%20configured%20on%20the%20server).

Check your connection to your `MySql` server please and also the parameters passed by your `Beam` job.

Comment: Trying to figure that out , only challenge is with DirectRunner this is working well, once i change to DataflowRunner thats when  the error pops up.

Comment: Why have a you a SSH tunnel in your example ?

Comment: so the production db requires a vpn connection, the tunnel is currently whitelisted  to allow connections without using the VPN

Comment: Apparently you are using 127.0.0.1 , which in this case, points to the Dataflow Worker VM, not your local environment anymore. You need to adjust the host accordingly when launching on Dataflow. Are you starting the job in the same VPC of the database? Otherwise, you may need to adjust firewall rules to make sure the machines can reach your database.